# High resolution UI on android issues

Tags: android, android-layout

I got primarily 2 issues.

In fact: I made an app which uses neat ui elements. Because of their detail they have to have a fitting resolution for every screen so i do big pictures in drawable-xhdpi, smaller ones in drawable-hdpi, etc...

The problem is: Using such high resolution UI elements slows down the whole app. It's not yet the worst-case but I am really stressed with the fact that I cannot make a "perfect" app which is beautiful and does not lag.

The second issue is: The app really becomes big when considering tablets also (xhdpi images are bigger). Out of compatibility reasons I dont want to make an extra tablet app...

Somebody got some information for high-res problems?

Answer (score 0):

When using large images on android i found the available heap can be a constraint.

As the lower-res images are scaled up the simple drawing-performance itself should not be any problem.

But every image you need to keep in the heap is reducing available memory for everything else you can do without getting onLowMemory callbacks.

There is an option within the Android Manifest to allow more heap on newer devices

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

This will not give you any more heap on most devices but if you try it on a modern device you can see if it makes a difference to decide if memory might be a problem.

It also can help to enable hardware acceleration.

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```

Another option is to improve performance on images which you need often.
The BitmapFactory.Options have an inPurgeable which control if the Bitmap is freed when memory is low.

But ... even if memory is a problem it is morelikely that the views have a too complicated layout.